# MOTD printing twice with "PrintMotd no"

Tags: 14.04, motd

I looked at other posts on here but none seemed to help. Whether I set `PrintMotd` to "no" or "yes" in the  `etc/ssh/` directory under `sshd_config` as long as I have a "motd" file under in `etc/` it gets printed twice.

Is there a different file that I need to edit that got messed up somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a fix I commented out `session    optional     pam_motd.so` in the `sshd` file which is found under `etc/pam.d`.

If there is a more proper solution to replace mine please post it as well.

Answer (score 4):

For me it was two places causing motd to be displayed twice:

1) pam.d & 2) sshd itself

To start fixing it:

`~> cd /etc/pam.d/
~> grep -i motd *`

and then editing /etc/pam.d/sshd (may differ from version to version so confirm with grep output) and hash out these two lines:

`session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
 session    optional     pam_motd.so noupdate`

My `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` also had `#PrintMotd=yes` (default is yes so it was active even if it was #'d out)

---

In the end I set `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` MOTD option to `PrintMotd=no` (not removed the # and set to no to replace the default) and enabled the `/etc/pam.d/sshd` motd lines so the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` option `printlastlog=yes` will print the last login information after the pam.d motd is displayed.

Pam will also use the options in `/etc/update-motd.d/` to customise the `/etc/motd` as well which sshd will not do as it will simply display what is already there.

Answer (score 0):

As @Leb pointed out, there's also a `pam_motd.so` entry to print the `/etc/motd` file, so you should pick one of either telling `sshd` to print it via the `PrintMotd yes` option, *or* using `pam_motd`.

Since `pam_motd` is used by default for both dynamic and static chunks of the message on Ubuntu, **you're probably better off disabling the additional `sshd` printing of the message by setting `PrintMotd no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`**.